# Open DialogFragment in an some Activity using AndroidX library, still's possible?

Tags: android, android-activity, androidx, android-dialogfragment

i have a Activity and i need open an DialogFragment in this activity, previously this was possible when using just:

```java
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                InfoLocalizacao infoLocalizacao = new InfoLocalizacao();
                infoLocalizacao.show(fragmentManager, "InfoLocalizacao");"InfoLocalizacao");
            ...
```

Using this method was needed just using the FragmentManager object, but, currently, this method returns this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.example.agrolucros2019.frags_e_actvs.venda.AddAnuncioActivity.InfoLocalizacao must be a public static class to be  properly recreated from instance state.
```

This my DialogFragment code:

```java
public class InfoLocalizacao extends DialogFragment{
        @NotNull
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("A Localização é importante");
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_location_on_24dp);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.avisoVenda)
                    .setPositiveButton("Estou Ciente", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ":)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
            return builder.create();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Until now, what i got was to make the Class InfoLocalizacao be Static, it work great, but, for the static class i can't to use non-static methods, like Toast.makeText, which I had to remove from my code;

Stayed like this:

```
public static class InfoLocalizacao extends DialogFragment{
    @NotNull
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("A Localização é importante");
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_location_on_24dp);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.avisoVenda)
                .setPositiveButton("Estou Ciente", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ":)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```